# Recursively find and move corrupted PDFs

Tags: ubuntu, pdf, recursive, corruption

#### The Issue

I was using `python-skydrive` to download files to my PC, and I accidentally corrupted a good amount of my PDF files. When I try to view them in Document Viewer, I get the following error message:

> File type plain text document (text/plain) is not supported

```
 $file ny.pdf
 $ny.pdf
```

#### My Request

I'm looking for a command line tool or snippet that will allow me to recursively find PDF files in a folder and  its subfolders, and then move corrupted files to a designated folder.

I'm using Ubuntu 13.10 on an x64 PC.

Comment: Can you tell us more about how were the files corrupted?

Comment: What does `file <filename>` gives as an output for a "corrupted" file? That may be a good way to discriminate them.

Comment: I was using the `skydrive-d` framework to download `PDF`, `.docx`, `.xlsx`, `.tex` files. Only the PDF files were corrupted--in particular, the ones I created with Adobe Acrobat or concatenated to other PDF files. I'm not trying to recover the files, just to remove them.

Comment: @Igeorget I get

$file ny.pdf

$ny.pdf: empty

Comment: Well, if all your corrupted files are empty, you can just class them by size, with `find . -name '*.pdf' -size 0` but maybe this is not the case for all your corrupted files.

Comment: OK--that works for me. Now, how do I move all of them?

Comment: with the `find` command! :-) I'll make a proper answer.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not new to Linux but I am command line-shy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After investigation (see the comments in the question), it appeared that the "corrupted" files were in fact empty. This can happen when a downloading program create the entries in the filesystem but fails before having downloaded their content.

To look for them in the current directory and its subdirectories and move them to a directory called `trash` in your home directory for example, you can use the `find` command.

```
find . -name '*.pdf' -size 0 -exec mv -t ~/trash {} \+
```